# Embedding radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'd like to embed radio buttons inside more radio buttons, like this : https://jsfiddle.net/xa6ow1jq/

The fiddle behaves exactly like I want it to, however it seems to be a lot of code just for a 2x3 grid, and I'm planning to have at least a 3xN grid (3 layers of N buttons each, N being at least 10, but many more if the user keeps scrolling)... So I was wondering if anyone knew/could think of more efficient ways to do this. (Using php and/or javascript and/or jquery and/or jquery UI)

(I'm a javascript & jquery noob, currently (self) learning it since yesterday, so I'd appreciate if you could be gentle with technical terms and give as much explications as possible).

Thanks in advance.

The javascript code in the fiddle :

```
// main buttons
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ap").click(function(){
        $(".a").toggle();
        $(".b").hide();
        $(".c").hide();
        $(".a.l").hide();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bp").click(function(){
        $(".a").hide();
        $(".b").toggle();
        $(".c").hide();
        $(".b.l").hide();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cp").click(function(){
        $(".a").hide();
        $(".b").hide();
        $(".c").toggle();
        $(".c.l").hide();
    });
});

//secondary buttons
//a
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".a1").click(function(){
        $(".a1.l").toggle();
        $(".a2.l").hide();
        $(".a3.l").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".a2").click(function(){
        $(".a1.l").hide();
        $(".a2.l").toggle();
        $(".a3.l").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".a3").click(function(){
        $(".a1.l").hide();
        $(".a2.l").hide();
        $(".a3.l").toggle();
    });
});
//b
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b1").click(function(){
        $(".b1.l").toggle();
        $(".b2.l").hide();
        $(".b3.l").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b2").click(function(){
        $(".b1.l").hide();
        $(".b2.l").toggle();
        $(".b3.l").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b3").click(function(){
        $(".b1.l").hide();
        $(".b2.l").hide();
        $(".b3.l").toggle();
    });
});
//c
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".c1").click(function(){
        $(".c1.l").toggle();
        $(".c2.l").hide();
        $(".c3.l").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".c2").click(function(){
        $(".c1.l").hide();
        $(".c2.l").toggle();
        $(".c3.l").hide();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".c3").click(function(){
        $(".c1.l").hide();
        $(".c2.l").hide();
        $(".c3.l").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. Use the `$(document).ready()` event once.
 2. If you have a functionality that is being repeated in your code - consider writing a function and calling it, instead of writing the same code over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Make formation of your html below, so you can deal with 3xN rows, you need to pop into array shown in javascript as `// here` and your HTML accordingly to achieve,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var groups = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    // creating simple js array too use for DOM manipulation

  $.each(groups, function(k, id) {
      // loops groups array we just created id variable contains a, b and then c
    $('#' + id).hide();
      // will evaluate as $('#a').hide();
    $('#' + id + 'l').hide();
      // will evaluate as $('#al').hide();
  });

  $(".button").click(function() {
    // bind click event on DOM items having class name as 'button'

    var button_id = $(this).data('id'); 
      /* $(this) will get us which button has been clicked, every 
      time click event occurs on DOM items having button class 
      and $(this).data(id); will get us clicked button's data-id attribute */

    $('#' + button_id).toggle(); // toogle

    var hide = $.grep(groups, function(value) { 
      // http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/
      return value != button_id;
    });

    $.each(hide, function(k, id) {
      // http://api.jquery.com/each/
      $('#' + id).hide();
    });

  });

  var selector = []; // initialize blank array

  $.each(groups, function(k) {
    selector.push('.' + groups[k]); 
      /* push groups array's elements with an extra .
      so, .a .b and .c */

  });

    // join array elements with ,
  selector = selector.join(',');
    // now selector is string, having value .a,.b,.c
    // https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

  $(selector).click(function() {
    // binding an event to the string we just created, follow the link above to get more idea

    var button_id = $(this).data('id'); // clicked button's data-id attribute
    var class_id = $(this).attr('class'); // clicked button's class

    var flag = $('.' + class_id + 'l').filter('[data-id="' + button_id + '"]').is(':visible');
      /* for later use, will be true if elements with matched filter conditions is visible in DOM,
      false otherwise */

    $.each(groups, function(k, id) {
      $('#' + id + 'l').children().hide();
        // https://api.jquery.com/children/
    });

    $.each(groups, function(k, id) {
      $('#' + id + 'l').hide();
    });

    $('#' + class_id + 'l').show();

    if (flag)
      $('.' + class_id + 'l').filter('[data-id="' + button_id + '"]').hide();
    else
      $('.' + class_id + 'l').filter('[data-id="' + button_id + '"]').show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-id="a">Toggle a</button>
<button class="button" data-id="b">Toggle b</button>
<button class="button" data-id="c">Toggle c</button>

<div id="a">
  <div class="a" data-id="1"><button>Toggle a1</button></div>
  <div class="a" data-id="2"><button>Toggle a2</button></div>
  <div class="a" data-id="3"><button>Toggle a3</button></div>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <div class="b" data-id="1"><button>Toggle b1</button></div>
  <div class="b" data-id="2"><button>Toggle b2</button></div>
  <div class="b" data-id="3"><button>Toggle b3</button></div>
</div>

<div id="c">
  <div class="c" data-id="1"><button>Toggle c1</button></div>
  <div class="c" data-id="2"><button>Toggle c2</button></div>
  <div class="c" data-id="3"><button>Toggle c3</button></div>
</div>

<div id="al">
  <div class="al" data-id="1">this is line a1</div>
  <div class="al" data-id="2">this is line a2</div>
  <div class="al" data-id="3">this is line a3</div>
</div>

<div id="bl">
  <div class="bl" data-id="1">this is line b1</div>
  <div class="bl" data-id="2">this is line b2</div>
  <div class="bl" data-id="3">this is line b3</div>
</div>

<div id="cl">
  <div class="cl" data-id="1">this is line c1</div>
  <div class="cl" data-id="2">this is line c2</div>
  <div class="cl" data-id="3">this is line c3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost does what I need, except for one thing : if for instance I click button A, then button A1, and then button B (or button A again), the "this is line A1" div doesn't disappear. I'm currently trying to understand your javascript code, both so I can fix this, and because I'd like to understand it to become better at javascript, but it's really complicated for me. I'd appreciate if you could take a moment to fix it and/or to comment the JS code to help me understand what each line does.

Comment: So, I was able to understand a part of the code and fix it, by adding these two lines : `15 : $('#' + button_id + 'l').hide();` and `23 :  $('#' + id +'l').hide();`. I still don't understand what comes after the `28 : var selector = [];` line and would still appreciate if you could comment the code to help me understand it ! In any case, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Moreover, if I am right, this works for 2xN buttons but it still needs adaptation for 3xN buttons, right ?

Comment: Here you go mate, see my edited answer, i have also added this code for improvement in codereview, if you want to check it out, [click here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92863/). And yes, im leaving that bug upto to you as a practice :) , i cant get it the meaning of 2xN, if you could show me a fiddle of 4xN, i could understand.